# Generating random numbers between 0 and y and x being the amount generated in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need help with generating random numbers between 0 and  y and x being the amount generated in java, as you can see I am almost there, but sorting them at the end, is giving me trouble please help me get this corrected!

```
   //imports
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
//Class
public class RandomGen {
    //Main Method
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Prepare Scanner
     Scanner randomScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Between 0 and what integer would you like to generate random Integers? ");
        int y = randomScanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Please Specify the number of Random integers you    would like:");
        int x= randomScanner.nextInt();

        Random pseudo = new Random();
        //Initialize Random
        for(int i =0; i<x; i++) {

            System.out.println(pseudo.nextInt(y+1));


        }

    }

}
```

//This code Generates the Randoms Just Fine! Now I need them sorted!
//The Code below these lines has too many syntax errors
//What Can I add to the above code to make this a simple organization of //this information, I need an array created and then have it organized.
//Below is my failed attempt at it, can anyone keep the ABOVE code simple?

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomInt {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] increasingRandoms(int x, int y);
    {

    //establishing an array

     Scanner randomScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Between 0 and what integer would you like to generate random Integers? ");
        y = randomScanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Please Specify the number of Random integers you    would like:");
        x= randomScanner.nextInt();

        //Setting x to pseudoRandom into an array in order to sort later
        int[] pseudoRandom = new int [x];


      for(int i =0; i< x; i++){

          Random pseudo = new Random();

    pseudoRandom[i] = pseudo.nextInt(y);
      }
      //returning an array in ascending order
      Arrays.sort(pseudoRandom);
      return pseudoRandom;
    }

    for(int number : increasingRandoms(y, x)) {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the array returned by increasingRandoms(x,y) in a variable first then use the variable in the enhanced for loop instead of using the method directly.

```
int[] temp=increasingRandoms(y, x);
for(int number : temp) {
    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

Also, I dont see why you should be creating a new object on each loop iteration, its better to create one Random object before entering the loop and then just call nextInt(int) in the loop

```
   int[] pseudoRandom = new int [x];


Random pseudo = new Random();

  for(int i =0; i< x; i++){

pseudoRandom[i] = pseudo.nextInt(y);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Java 8 then there's a nice easy solution:

```
int[] myRandomNumbers = new Random().ints(x, 0, y).sorted().toArray();
```